# Youtube iframe autoplay does not work in Chromium but works in Firefox on Manjaro Linux

Tags: html, google-chrome, youtube, chromium

I wrote a `iframe` code to start youtube video automatically. my code is :

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/QeZdL1Oq9sQ?controls=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;rel=0&amp;autoplay=1&amp;loop=1&amp;mute=1&amp;vq=default&amp;playlist=QeZdL1Oq9sQ" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"></iframe>
```

I paste this code to jsFiddle. when I open jsFiddle on Firefox, video start to play automatically. But when I open it in Chromium, video does not start. I added `mute=1` and `autoplay=1` but did not work. How can I fix this ?

jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/Lx15on63/

```
Firefox : 62.0 (64-bit)

Chromium : 69.0.3497.81 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)
```

---

I updated chromium to `69.0.3497.92` but still autoplay does not work on Chromium. I tried same thing on Windows with same Chrome, there is no trouble. is it Linux issue ?

---

I tried this jsfiddle with chromium Version `76.0.3809.100 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit)` and autoplay works

Answer (score 1):

Your code works for me on windows without any changes.

You can try to [turn on autoplay explicitly](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes#iframe)

```
<iframe src="yourvideolink" allow="autoplay; fullscreen">
```

Comment: @user4757345 Version 69.0.3497.92 (Official Build) (64-bit) Win7-x64

Comment: I tried on Chrome Windows version and I saw autoplay works on Windows but does not work on Linux. I updated question title.